# Atheros Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: bluetooth, atheros

**FIXED**, take a look at the [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1352821)!

I have a very peculiar problem on Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 x64. My internal WiFi/Bluetooth adapter gets detected and WiFi works fine. Its Bluetooth functionality also gets detected, all GUI and command line commands *seem* to work normally (they return no errors) but neither are other Bluetooth devices detected, nor can other devices see my laptop. I suspected it to be an antenna problem (the symptoms are identical), but with Windows 8.1 it works perfectly.

My laptop is an Acer Aspire E3-111-C1LY

```
root@pantheratigris:~# hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    00:71:CC:60:XX:XX              // a full MAC was displayed
root@pantheratigris:~# time hcitool scan   // with nearby Bluetooth visible Android phone
Scanning ...

real    0m10.248s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.005s
matega@pantheratigris:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b47f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e078 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
matega@pantheratigris:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
matega@pantheratigris:~$ hciconfig --all
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:71:CC:60:XX:XX  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1212 acl:0 sco:0 events:72 errors:0
    TX bytes:2050 acl:0 sco:0 commands:72 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x8f
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ubuntu-gnome-0'
    Class: 0x7c0100
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x3101
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x1
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
matega@pantheratigris:~$
```

Comment: It works now for me; I submitted the patch to [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1352821).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you post the results of `lsusb` and `hciconfig --all`as there are some chipsets that are not yet supported correctly

I was able to patch a couple modules so that your bluetooth should work in 14.10 with the 3.16.0-28 64 bit kernel, check with `uname -a` hopefully it shows x86_64 also

New modules zipped can be found https://www.dropbox.com/s/kufg12cf28eh36l/Ubuntu1410.zip?dl=0 extract them to desktop then in terminal `sudo mv /lib/modules/3.16.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko.bak`

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb

sudo mv /lib/modules/3.16.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak
cd Desktop
cd Ubuntu1410
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
sudo cp ath3k.ko /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
sudo modprobe ath3k
sudo modprobe btusb
```

With any luck it will work as I haven't witnessed the xhci glitch with loading the firmware in 14.10 like it was in 14.04

New edit 1/1/2015, a different method with patched ath3k.c and btusb.c files
Edit: download this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajxndivy4vwgapv/test.zip?dl=0 and extract it to /home so you have a folder named test in home, then in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd test
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make all
sudo modprobe -r ath3k
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko.bak
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak
sudo cp ath3k.ko  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp btusb.ko  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
```

then Reboot.

Comment: At first I though Bluetooth was also provided by the `AR9565`, so I frowned upon your suggestion to run `lsusb`. Oh was I wrong; I'll go and edit my question.

Comment: I suspect this device is not supported yet by Ubuntu in 14.10, in terminal enter

Comment: modinfo ath3k | grep -i e078

Comment: I think I found the [corresponding bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1352821). Also, `modinfo ath3k | grep -i e078` does not output anything. I'll consider this question moot then and markyou answer as the accepted one.
(on a side note, shouldn't `ath9k` handle this as it's an AR9XXX? Anyway, `modinfo`ing that doesn't yield anything containing e078 either.)

Comment: Eventually the Ubuntu 14.10 kernel will be patched to support your 0489:e078 as patches have been applied to btusb and ath3k in bluetooth next, you will need to install package linux-firmware so ath3k can load the firmware when it does get support

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for compiling these for me! Unfortunately, they fail to load: `Exec format error`, although my kernel version mathces, even the x86_64. How did you do this, and how can I attempt this too?

Comment: Try a reboot and see if `lsmod | grep ath3k` shows ath3k as it should.  I will see if I can find a good tutorial on how to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19820/discussion-between-matega-and-user300665).

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below command and install the bluetooth genome again and then check whether you are able to connect to the bluetooth device,

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth blueman bluez-hcidump bluewho python-bluez  bluez-tools
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you; I've already tried installing additional Bluetooth packages from another answer here, but it didn't help. My repos (the default ones) don't have the `bluez-hcidump` package. The `python-bluez` and `blueman` packages were new, I installed them, but as of now it didn't help.